# Automating a form which requires a signed in user using Cypress

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

I am currently working on automating a form (Questionnaire), in order for a user to fill out this form they must be logged in.

After a user logs in, and chooses an option on the questionnaire, an API call is directly made to save this in the database.

I am writing a test using Cypress and have currently managed to automate the log in process, and choosing the options through the form. However, since I have gone through the questionaire with this user, the results are saved down.

My question is, how can I automate this using Cypress? Do I need to delete and re-create the user each time (API currently doesn't support delete functionality, only disable). Am I to render the component like one does when writing unit tests (e.g. React Testing Library) - but this would defeat the purpose end-to-end automation hence (in my opinion) preference is that we actually go through the questioner.

I am fairly new to writing tests and any guidance would be much appreciated. I am sure there are an abundance of such patterns out there and I just need to figure it out.

What does one usually do when automating a webpage using cypress that requires an authenticated user and saves the state of the user, the test suite is run multiple times a day - and there is (currently) no option to delete a user.

Comment: Instead of deleting or recreating the user each time, you can manage the test data within your tests. This means that before each test run, you can set up the necessary preconditions (create a new user) and clean up any post-test state (reset user data) to ensure a consistent starting point for each test. This approach allows you to have better control over the test environment.

Comment: That's very true. But 'clean up' would mean creating and deleting the user, the API doesn't have an option to delete a user only disable. I think Lola's response might work where I intercept the requests. I'm going to give that a go but if you have any more information to pass to me, I'd be extermely grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could handle the situation by intercepting the POST requests and stubbing them, so that the backend never gets updated.

For reference, see [cy.intercept() - spying and response stubbing](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Usage)

> ```js
> cy.intercept('POST', '/users*', {
>   statusCode: 201,
>   body: {
>    name: 'Peter Pan',
>   },
> })
> ```

This is (marginally?) better than unit testing, because you are in fact confirming that the API is being hit and that the correct calls are being made by the front end.

Comment: Thank you. This has worked. By adding the intercept, whenever it makes a request, it doesn't actually hit the backend, as OP suggested. So this is an ideal solution. Thank you!